# Efficient way to process record separated by pipe?

Tags: java

I've a string which contains data concatenated by pipe (|)

Example: 5|aa@gmail.com|477|en|87477

The string has ~15 fields concatenated by pipe.

It could be possible that some field may have empty data:
Example: 5|aa@gmail.com||en|87477

How can I efficiently get all the individual fields in Java 1.6?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the Split method offered by java

```
String str = "5|aa@gmail.com|477|en|87477";
String[] data = str.split("\\|");
for(String s : data){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

The output i get is

```
5
aa@gmail.com
477
en
87477
```

As it's just an array of string you access the data as you want, ie data[1] gives aa@gmail.com

Comment: Is this approach better as compared to StringTokenizer?? Will it take care if there is no data i.e. 2 consecutive pipes ??

Comment: Alan, this won't work as expected if there are empty tokens at the end of the string like "5|aa@gmail.com|477|en||||87477||x|||".

Comment: Another of the answers offers suggestions for dealing with empty tokens at the end. In the middle, it'll work as expected. The advantage over StringTokenizer is that it's much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the `String.split` answer because it's simplest. Its two downsides are:

1. uses a regex instead of just finding a single char; a bit of extra overhead for the generalization
2. has to re-compile the regex pattern each time

To get a slight increase, if you need it, you can pre-compile the pattern and then use that to split:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
private static final Pattern BAR_REGEX = Pattern.compile( Pattern.quote("|") );
```

and then in your method:

```
String[] splits = BAR_REGEX.split( inputString );
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). Very fast and does indeed handle 'missing' tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Alan's solution will work most times except if you have empty token(s) in the end. For example,

> String str = "5|aa@gmail.com|477|en||||87477||x|||";

You could solve this by

- Using another variant of split with a negative value for limit, (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))

> String str = "5|aa@gmail.com|477|en||||87477||x|||";
>
> str.split("\\|", -1);

- or use commons.StringUtils.splitPreserveAllTokens(str, delim)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `StringTokenizer` class.